# JPA2 with Grails and GORM?

Tags: grails, jpa, jpa-2.0, grails-orm, jpa-2.1

I have a need to use GORM, but to use certain libraries which require JPA 2 or 2.1. I see there is a plugin here (http://grails.org/plugin/gorm-jpa) for using GORM with JPA 1, but it's not been updated since 2012.

Is there a way to use GORM and JPA 2.x together? If not, what steps would one need to take to develop such capabilities?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can look for the documentation for gorm: http://projects.spring.io/grails-data-mapping/manual/index.html and source https://github.com/grails/grails-data-mapping

Comment: I've seen the docs, but nothing that specifically covers JPA2. Is there something there I'm missing?